# Access VBA recordCount returning 0 when records exist

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm attempting to create a function to add n workdays to a date. This obviously needs to take into account weekends and holidays. The weekend part works fine, but I used a table to list all of the holidays and I can't get my query to pull the accurate recordCount. It insists the count is always zero. Here is my code:

```
Public Function dateAddNoWeekends(dt1 As Date, genDate As Integer)
Dim i As Integer
Dim date1 As Date
Dim date2 As Date
Dim holidays As Boolean
Dim isWeekday As Boolean
Dim dayOfWeek As Integer
Dim numDays As Integer
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim sql As String
Set db = CurrentDb
date1 = dt1
date2 = date1
i = 0
numDays = genDate

sql = "SELECT * FROM Holidays WHERE holidayDate = " & date2
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sql)

Debug.Print date2

Do While i < numDays
    If Not isWeekday Then date2 = date2 + 1
    dayOfWeek = Weekday(date2)

    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
        Debug.Print rs.RecordCount
        holidays = True
    Else
        holidays = False
        Debug.Print rs.RecordCount
    End If

    If dayOfWeek > 1 And dayOfWeek < 7 And holidays = False Then
        If i < numDays - 1 Then date2 = (date2 + 1)
            isWeekday = True
            i = i + 1
        Else: isWeekday = False
        End If
Loop

rs.Close
Debug.Print date2
```

Comment: Maybe a problem with the date format? Try using a constant date like '2017-12-25' for test.

Comment: like this? sql = "SELECT * FROM Holidays WHERE holidayDate = '7/1/2017'"    This yields a data type mismatch.

Comment: After `Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sql)` add `rs.MoveLast`.  Also maybe `"SELECT * FROM Holidays WHERE holidayDate = " & CLNG(date2)`.  I hate dates in Access. :)

Comment: Tried all of these things, but it doesn't seem to work :/ Using rs.MoveLast gives me a run time error that says "no current record".

Comment: It is an expensive operation to return multiple rows just for the Recordcount property.  Besides, Recordcount is not guaranteed to be accurate unless you do a `rs.MoveLast`. I forget the details, but it I think it depends on the recordset type (Dynaset, Snapshot, etc.).  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821452.aspx. Instead, use the SQL **Count()** aggregate function to have the query engine count all the rows for you.

Comment: Like this `sql = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Holidays WHERE holidayDate = #" & Format(date2, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#"`.  Any time you have a string and concatenate a variable, you must consider what datatype and how it's going to be represented in a string.

Comment: Also, it looks like the code expects the query to be updated for every iteration of the loop, for every new value of date2.  That will not happen.  The query is only being executed **once** and will only return rows if a holiday matches the initial value of date2 exactly.  Then for the rest of the loop it remains the same.

Comment: I suspect that you'll need to do more debugging to get the code right, or that it will be rather slow if you end up  running a new query for every date in between. Try searching the web for `access add only working day to date` or search SO for `[ms-access] add working days` or similar variations.  Working-day problems have been discussed many times.  I hope my other hints help.  Good luck.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Only, how do you get the value from "count(*)? I tried rs.fields("Count") and rs.fields(Count(*)) as well as rs!Total with no results. I'll have to do some more looking for code that works for my purpose and see if i can snag it or use it to develop my own.

Comment: Never mind, figured that out :)

Comment: If you don't need any fields from the recordset, could use DCount() instead.

Comment: I meant to update this thread -- that is actually what I ended up doing! I declared a variable for it at the top of the loop (so that it would update correctly each time) and used Dcount to count from date2 to date2. Everything works perfectly now!

Comment: @June7 add your comment as an answer so eleyna can mark it as answered.

Comment: Looks like she figured it out just before I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, I declared a variable at the top of the loop (so that it would update correctly each time) and assigned a Dcount function to count from date2 to date2.